# Azure Storage Account: How to rename/move a Blob within a Container

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk-python

I am using [Microsoft Azure SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python) and I want to move or rename a Blob  within the same container.

For example, how to move this blob

```
https://demostorage.blob.core.windows.net/container-a/folder1/file1.jpg
```

into this?

```
https://demostorage.blob.core.windows.net/container-a/folder2/file2.jpg
```

Comment: I think you can accomplish that by using the [`BlobClient.start_copy_from_url`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/python/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobclient?source=recommendations&view=storage-py-v12#start-copy-from-url-source-url--metadata-none--incremental-copy-false----kwargs-) method to copy from the source blob to the target, and then, deleting the source blob.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule I agree, I'm trying to understand if there is a simpler way given that the file remain within the container. As far as I understood, the `start_copy_from_url` method still implements an asynchronous copy of the file (download/upload)

Answer (score 0):

After reproducing from my end I could able to achieve this using `copy_blob` of azure-storage versioned 0.20.0.

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobService

accountName = "<YourAccountName>"
accountKey = "<YourAccountKey>"

blob_service = BlobService(accountName ,accountKey )
sourceFileName = 'file1.png'
destinationFileName = 'file2.png'
sourcePath = 'container1/folder1'
destinationPath = 'container1/folder2'

blob_url = blob_service.make_blob_url(sourcePath,sourceFileName)
blob_service.copy_blob(destinationPath, destinationFileName, blob_url)
```

[image]