# How to rename an already existing blob in azure storage explorer using python

Tags: python, azure, azure-blob-storage, blob, rename

I want to rename a blob file in Azure storage explorer. It's in a folder of a specific blob container.I'm using **python**.

I used this code.

```
sourceFileName = abc.xlsx
destinationFileName = xyz.xlsx
sourcePath = 'cloudops-resources/outputs/'
destinationPath = 'cloudops-resources/outputs/'

blob_url = blob_service.make_blob_url(sourcePath,sourceFileName)
blob_service.copy_blob(destinationPath, destinationFileName, blob_url)
```

But there is no blob_service module in the azure.storage.blob.I tried using BlockBlobService as well.But those can't be imported.

I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73941246/azure-storage-account-how-to-rename-move-a-blob-within-a-container) and I tried using [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58921410/dynamic-rename-azure-blob-if-already-uploaded) codes as well.

Can someone please tell me how to rename an already existing blob using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got the below results:**

> Can someone please tell me how to rename an already existing blob using python?

Initially, I have an xlsx file with the name **`sample1.xlsx`** in azure blob storage.

**Portal:**

[image]

You can use the below code to rename the file name.

**Code:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

connection_string = "Your storage connection string"
container_name = "test3"
blob_name = "sample1.xlsx"
new_blob_name = "sample567.xlsx"

blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, blob_name)
new_blob_client = blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container_name, new_blob_name)

# Copy the blob to the new name
new_blob_client.start_copy_from_url(blob_client.url)

# Delete the original blob
blob_client.delete_blob()
print("The blob is Renamed successfully:",{new_blob_name})
```

**Output:**

```
The blob is Renamed successfully: {'sample567.xlsx'}
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Comment: Thank u very much. Can u please tell me how to specify the blob name inside a folder in a container?

Comment: I tried putting the folder name in the container name like this. container_name = "cloudops-resources/outputs". But it doesn't work

Comment: You can use the `blob_name = "folder1/sample1.xlsx" and new_blob name = "folder1/sample567.xlsx"`

Comment: That was a success.Thanks a lot!!!